# Laravel - Guzzle Request / cURL error 6: Could not resolve host

Tags: php, laravel, curl, guzzle

I try to make an API Request to the Github API just for testing. I installed the latest Guzzle Version ( "guzzle/guzzle": "^3.9" )  on my Laravel 5.1 APP.
In my `routes.php` i have the following Code:

```
Route::get('guzzle/{username}', function($username) {
    $client = new Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://api.github.com/users/',
    ]);
    $response = $client->get("/users/$username");
    dd($response);
});
```

If i now visit the URL domain.dev/github/kayyyy i get the Error `cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: users`.

Why am i getting this Error?

If i visit https://api.github.com/users/kayyyy i can see the `json` output.

**I am also using Homestead / Vagrant is this maybe a Problem that the host cant be resolved?**

**EDIT**
If i try this without the base_uri it works.

```
Route::get('guzzle/{username}', function($username) {
   $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
    $response = $client->get("https://api.github.com/users/$username");
    dd($response);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay i solved it, stupid mistake by me.
I used `new Client`.

And it should be of course `new GuzzleHttp\Client`

As it is just for testing in my `routes.php` i did not the `Namespace`

Thanks for your help everybody.

Answer (score 5):

Why are you calling `$client->get->()->send()`? In particular, why are you chaining the send() method at the end? The documentation does not append the `send()` method when demonstrating what seems to be the same action:

http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#creating-a-client

Also, did you consider the implications of this statement on the above-cited manual page?

> When a relative URI is provided to a client, the client will combine the base URI with the relative URI using the rules described in RFC 3986, section 2.

Answer (score 4):

Actually a variable interpolation is not possible within single quotes. This means that you currently are calling `users/$username` and the `$username` variable gets not replaced with its value.

In order to get it, you should use it in one of the following ways:

```
$response = $client->get("users/$username")->send();
$response = $client->get('users/' . $username)->send();
```

I personally prefer the second one as it is assumed to be faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yep, but this didnt worked, still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Your Laravel installer is very out of date. The only way to get the latest version is to remove and install again:

1. composer global remove laravel/installer
2. composer global require laravel/installer

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Paratron 
https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/1184#issuecomment-355295789
In my case, on cakephp 3.8 & docker 19.03.5, I was facing curl error due to some network issue. I restarted my cake-server docker container, & it worked like a charm.