# cURL error 6 in sending request with guzzle

Tags: laravel, curl, guzzle

In my laravel application, I want to send http request with guzzle.

Here is my code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user', [
  'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
```

This results :

cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: api.github.com

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel - Guzzle Request / cURL error 6: Could not resolve host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31923397/laravel-guzzle-request-curl-error-6-could-not-resolve-host)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to define your auth constant,

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
define("auth", \GuzzleHttp\RequestOptions::AUTH );
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user', [
  'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
```

Comment: you can refer from here https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html#auth

Comment: Also you are missing a ` \ `  in front of  `GuzzleHttp\Client()`